# Jquery .out() remove droppable class only if all draggables are removed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have 4 draggable options and 3 droppable buckets.  When I drag an option to a droppable, the draggable takes on the value of the bucket.  The droppable also takes on the class '.dropped'.  2 things I need:

1. When the draggable is removed from the bucket it looses the value
2. When all draggables are removed from a droppable, it looses the '.dropped' class

The problem I'm having is that the ui param in .out(event,ui) is empty (per http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-out) so I can't really grab any info from it to update the draggable value or count the number of draggables inside the droppable.

I've considered using a counter but there are 3 different droppables.  Any advice?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="drag-option span1 draggable" id="option1">Option 1</div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="drag-option span1 draggable" id="option2">Option 2</div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="drag-option span1 draggable" id="option3">Option 3</div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="drag-option span1 draggable" id="option4">Option 4</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="drop-option droppable span4" value="1">1</div>
    <div class="drop-option droppable span4" value="2">2</div>
    <div class="drop-option droppable span4" value="3">3</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
// Drag Drop functions
$('.draggable').draggable({containment: "#drag-radio"}).css('cursor','move');
$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ".drag-option",
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    // Make the drag option inherit the drop value
    drop: function(event,ui){
        ui.draggable.attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
        $(this).addClass('dropped');

    },
    // Remove draggable value and droppable .dropped class
    out: function(event,ui){
        ui.draggable.attr('value','');
        $(this).removeClass('dropped');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I probably mislead you some. The problem is that you are using `value` inside of 'div' tags. Div tags DO NOT have a `value` attribute, so that is why it is undefined. You need to change these to something else that can hold a value attribute.

[W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4)

Here is a new working JSFiddle, using `input` tags instead of divs. I made them readonly so that they cannot be typed into. It probably isn't your ideal solution, but I wanted to show you that you are doing things correctly, just that the div does not use the value attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/cFcup/5/

Comment: Actually, in the drop function the attr works fine setting the value.  It's just in the out that you can't grab the ui.draggable because ui is empty.  Using .prop doesn't work for either .drop or .out

Comment: I don't think there should be a difference between using `.attr` and `.prop` in this case. It's not an `<input>` element, so it doesn't have a dynamic value different from the HTML attribute.

Comment: That may be true, but using the document instead of the ui seems to be working.

Comment: Run it under the debugger it complains `Cannot call method 'prop' of undefined`.

Comment: How can you tell it's working in the fiddle? You don't have any CSS associated with the classes, so you can't tell if it's changing.

Comment: Once you drop an option next to 1, 2 or 3 you cannot move it again. It is removing the value/class or it would still let you drag it as it does if you keep it as the OP had with the ui.

Comment: But he wants to be able to drag the object out, that's what the `out` handler is supposed to react to.

Comment: Sorry about misleading you guys, I must be off my rocker today. I changed my post to where it is correct and makes more sense, though it does not necessarily provide an ideal solution to your problem.

Comment: What he should be using is `.data('value')`, not an attribute at all. But I don't think that's the problem. The problem is that `ui.draggable` and `document.draggable` are both undefined.

Comment: `ui.draggable` actually isn't undefined. The reason he was getting undefined is because he was getting the `ui.draggable.attr('value')` from a div, which has no value attribute at all, and hence got undefined. In my fiddle, I was able to get and alert from the `ui.draggable` using inputs with values. But you are correct that using `.data()` would be a better approach for drag/drop.

Comment: Of course `ui.draggable` is undefined, because `ui` is undefined. It says so right in the documentation he linked to.

Comment: And although `value` is not a standard attribute for DIVs, most browsers allow non-standard attributes. People have been using them for ages, HTML5 finally added the data-XXX attributes as a place for user-defined data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:\

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="drag-option span1 draggable" id="option1">Option 1</div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="drag-option span1 draggable" id="option2">Option 2</div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="drag-option span1 draggable" id="option3">Option 3</div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="drag-option span1 draggable" id="option4">Option 4</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="drop-option droppable span4" data-value="1" readonly>1</div>
    <div class="drop-option droppable span4" data-value="2" readonly>2</div>
    <div class="drop-option droppable span4" data-value="3" readonly>3</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    containment: "#drag-radio"
}).css('cursor', 'move');
$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ".drag-option",
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    // Make the drag option inherit the drop value
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.data('value', $(this).data('value'));
        alert(ui.draggable.data('value'));
        $(this).addClass('dropped');
    },
    // Remove draggable value and droppable .dropped class
    out: function (event, ui) {
        $(".draggable[data-value=" + $(this).data('value') + "]").data('value', '');
        $(this).removeClass('dropped');
    }
});
```

It uses a dataset attribute instead of the nonstandard value attribute. Then it uses a selector that matches on the dataset attribute to find the draggable that was removed, since there's no `ui` parameter to say which it was.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/cFcup/8/)

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't solve the problem.  The draggable is still retaining the value after being un-dropped.  Also, I need the droppable to keep the .dropped class unless ALL draggables have been removed.  In other words, if I have 2 draggables in a droppable and remove one, it will still have the .dropped class.  Basically, I want the droppable to remain highlighted until all draggables are removed.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. This seems to be a hole in the jQuery UI draggable/droppable API. When you drag something out, there doesn't seem to be a way to find out what was dragged. There's no event on the draggable that says it was removed, and the `out` event on the droppable doesn't say _what_ was removed. Maybe you should try posting the question in the jQuery Forum.